# seeing if a keyword in one Arraylist is in an element of another Arraylist

Tags: java

I've obtained an ArrayListof string for user inputted keywords now I'm trying to see if those keywords are present in the separate elements of another arraylist which is a catalogue of books. My code is shown below and the compiler keeps saying cannot find symbol when i compile the following code:

edit: i've changed the code as follows

```
 ArrayList<Book> catalogue; //was defined in another class
 ArrayList<String> keywords;// was created in a driver class through user input

 public ArrayList<String> getTitlesContainingKeyword(String keyword){

     ArrayList<String>results = new ArrayList<>();

     for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i ++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < catalogue.size(); j ++){
             if (catalogue.get(j).contains(keywords.get(i))) // the contains in this line is giving the error
             {
                 results.add(j); 
             }
         }
     }
      return results;
   }
```

it appears that the main problem is that catalogue is a book arraylist and keywords is a string arraylist

Comment: What is the use of the parameter `keyword` in your method ?

Comment: Which line is giving the error? Where are the various variables declared in your program?

Comment: What is `results`. What are the types of the ArrayList you are speaking of? please try to add a little more details

Answer (score 0):

You should simply check if the keyword exists or not. Why are you using get method ? Simply pass in the String to the contains, completely.

What I mean to say is:
1.  Get the keyword.
2. Check if it indeed is a valid keyword by calling the contains() on your keywords ArrayList. If it returns false, do not proceed to search the catalogues.
3. If it is, go over each catalogue and call its contains to see if the keyword is contained in that catalogue.

Your logic seems to be wrong in the code snippet.

Comment: i'm using a get method because it's part of a larger class and was set and i'm supposed to add the code that checks to see if the keywords are contained in the catalogue arraylist and then if they are display the keywords and the elements in the catalogue that contain the keyword

Comment: Your logic is far too convoluted for a task so simple. just use contains() of the ArrayList. Why loop ?

Comment: My thinking was that i would loop the Arraylists and then check to see if the first keyword was in each of the entries of the catalogue arraylist and so on and then to get all of the elements of the catalogue that contain the keyword into a results arraylist

Comment: No. If it not a keyword, why bother to check the catalogue?

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getTitlesContainingKeyword(String keyword){
    for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i ++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < catalogue.size(); j ++){
           if (catalogue.get(j).contains(keywords.get(i))) {
                 results.add(j);  // << who is results
            }
         }
        }
            return results;
        }
```

The error is being given by the compiler because you havn't declared `results` in your method. Compiler doesn't know what is this `results`, neither do you, nor me.

1. If it is supposed be an `ArrayList<String>`, then declare and create it as such.
2. Change your method return type to `ArrayList<String>` instead of `String`

   ```
   public ArrayList<String> getTitlesContainingKeyword(String keyword){

       ArrayList<String>results = new ArrayList<>();

      for (int i = 0; i < keywords.size(); i ++) {
          for (String catLog: catalogue){
             if (catLog.contains(keywords.get(i))) {
                results.add(catLog); 
               }
             }
           }
           return results;
         }
   ```

Comment: I changed the code to reflect those recommended changes but catalogue was declared as an arraylist book and not a string so that seems to be where the problem is.

Comment: What is the type of Catalogue array list? is it `ArrayList<Catalogue>` or `ArrayList<String>`. Please change your question with details

Comment: However, I have updated the answer assuming that `catalogue` is an array list of `String`